# native SQL query on spring java fails

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jparepository

I have this query in my repository in java with spring framework:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT cr.reviewer_name, cr.message, cr.rating, cr.source, cr.show_status, cr.created_date, " +
    "cr.group_index, string_agg(cr.type, ',') " +
    "FROM customer_review cr " +
    "WHERE cr.type LIKE 'NEWCAR%' AND cr.object_code = :objectCode AND cr.is_deleted NOT IN (true) " +
    "GROUP BY cr.reviewer_name, cr.message, cr.rating, cr.source, cr.show_status, cr.created_date, cr.group_index " +
    "LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object[]> findByObjectCode(@Param("objectCode") String objectCode, @Param("limit") Integer limit, @Param("offset") Integer offset);
```

I made sure the table name is exactly the same in the query. But it always returns the following error:

```
The column name group_index was not found in this ResultSet.
```

I tryed to rewrite the query, and run it manually on postgres and it works. But when I use it on my repository interface, it retuns the error.

Here is my table:

[image]

Comment: please show a description of your table.  And do you not want to use `@NamedNativeQuery`

Comment: i dont want to use @NamedNativeQuery

Comment: Where did you get a ResultSet?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but why the return type is a List of Object array?

Why don't you use a model or a projection spring?

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/projections.html